# Change caret position in textarea by click on button

Tags: javascript, position, caret

I have a textarea with this content :

```
[supreme] a test text or anything [/supreme]
```

I have a button too. **I want to when button clicked , textarea selected and change caret position to this :**

```
[supreme] a test text or anything  <caret postion> [/supreme]
```

How can i do this with javascript or jquery ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example. It could be done cleaner but it should get you started.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.button').click(function(e) {
    var $textArea = $('.textArea');
    var prevValue = $textArea.val();
    $textArea.focus().val('').val(prevValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="textArea">a test text or anything</textarea>
<button class="button">
CLick Me
</button>
```